# Request.IsAuthenticated return different value on https and http page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a project using asp.net mvc 5.1, asp.net identity 2.0. After I deploy it to IIS, when I go to secure page 'https://www.xxxx.com/Account/Login', after login,  if I go to https://www.xxxx.com. Request.IsAuthenticated  return true on _LoginPartial.cshtml page, but go to http://www.xxxx.com, always return false.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have the option set to only send the authentication cookie over HTTPS, therefore if you navigate to a page over HTTP, the authentication cookie is not sent and the application believes you to be unauthenticated.

The setting in question is `requireSSL` in the `system.web/authentication/forms` section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="auth" loginUrl="~/login" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

and this controls whether the `secure` property is used on the authentication cookie.

Since you are using HTTPS, I would recommend preventing the site from being navigated over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

RequireSSL will only allow the cookie to be transferred across https.  In case you have this specific requirement then you need to take additional precaution in the code.

But beware, of what you are doing at this point.

You can use Request.IsSecureConnection at appropriate place.  This could be in the module or in the base class on or in the filter.

An out of dated article is here, but can serve as a pointer.
http://r2d2.cc/2011/08/05/how-to-switch-between-http-and-https-in-asp-net-mvc2-and-allow-ajax-requests-from-site-master/

**Caution: Use with care, as you may need to take additional precaution on the server to avoid hijacking.**